# Curved line in Android layout

Tags: android, layout, line

Is there a simple way to create a curved line in an Android layout?

To give you an idea of what I mean, this is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The most simple way is to use an image. Can you?

Comment: Use a custom View and draw an arc.

Comment: use a ShapeDrawable with a custom Shape